# Subgroup of p-adic units

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-numbers, adeles

Let $\left(\widehat{\mathbb Z}\right)^\times=\prod_p{\mathbb Z}_p^\times$
be the unit group of the ring $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, which is the profinite completion of $\mathbb Z$.
We give it the product topology.
For a given prime $p$ let
$$
f_p=(1,p)\in\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\ \times\ \prod_{q\ne p}\mathbb{Z}_q^\times.
$$
Is the group generated by all $f_p$ dense in $\left(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\right)^\times$?

Comment: A subgroup is dense iff it is contained in $\ell\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ for no prime $\ell$. Given this, you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dense in the unit group, not the ring. I am not sure, whether a similar argument applies for the unit group.

Comment: TeX note: $\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times$ `\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times` puts the `\times` too high.  To get it at the proper level, you can `\smash` the `\widehat{\mathbb Z}` to force TeX to forget its height:  $\smash{\widehat{\mathbb Z}}^\times$ `\smash{\widehat{\mathbb Z}}^\times`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: No, the times is correct, otherwise we have the profinite completion of the unit group of $\mathbb Z$, which is $\{\pm 1\}$. I have put brackets around the ring, to make it clear, what I mean.

Comment: Don't worry, I think there was no danger that you are misunderstood. Similarly $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is not the $p$-adic completion of $\{\pm1\}$.

Comment: But $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}^\times}$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More is true: the generating set $\{f_p:\text{$p$ is a prime}\}$ is dense in $\smash{\widehat{\mathbb Z}}^\times$. To see this, it suffices to show that, for any finite set of primes $S$, the projection of the above generating set onto $\prod_{q\in S}\mathbb{Z}_q^\times$ is dense. Let $t$ be a positive integer whose prime factors are from $S$, and let $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/t\mathbb{Z})^\times$ be a reduced residue class modulo $t$. Then it suffices to show that there is a prime $p\notin S$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod{t}$. Such a prime exists by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, and we are done.